# magento 2 change multiselct to ui select for custom customer attribute

Tags: admin, magento2.4, uicomponent, customer-attribute, ui-select

I want to create a UI select in the customer account area in ADMIN for custom attributes.
something like this ->
https://dolphinwebsolution.com/magento-2-add-ui-select-component-with-search-filter-in-admin-form

I am not sure how to get this even in the admin area for attributes.

When I created the attribute with InsallData I set it for multi-select so now I can see my custom attribute as a multi-select.

has anyone done this or is this possible for customer attribute?